# How to validate Avro format data with different schema

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

```
private static final String json = "{" + "\"name\":\"Frank\"," + "\"age\":\"47\"" + "}";
private static final Schema schema1 = new Schema.Parser().parse("{ \"type\":\"record\", \"namespace\":\"foo\", \"name\":\"Person\", \"fields\":[ { \"name\":\"name\", \"type\":\"string\" }, { \"name\":\"age\", \"type\":\"string\" } ] }");
private static final Schema schema2 = new Schema.Parser().setValidate(true).parse("{ \"type\":\"record\", \"namespace\":\"foo\", \"name\":\"Person\", \"fields\":[ { \"name\":\"name\", \"type\":\"string\" }, { \"name\":\"age\", \"type\":\"int\" } ] }");
```

1)if we going  to validate above json with schema1 it should say true

2)if we going to validate above json with schema2 it should say false due to "age" field is int according to schema, but in json it is string

```
public static boolean validateJson(byte[] data, Schema schema) throws Exception {
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
    GenericDatumReader<Object> reader = null;
    Object datum = null;
    BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder =
            DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(input, null);
    try {
        reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(schema);
        DatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(input, null);
        reader.read(din, decoder);
        return true;
    } catch (AvroTypeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
    GenericDatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, json);
    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
    Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
    writer.write(datum, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: And? What do you get for 2 ? Do you use Avro 1.8 libs ?

Comment: Thanks Harold, always getting true.when i print json data(json & schema2)getting age value is 2 as int,but when i print data(json & schema1)age value is 47 as string

Comment: using Avro 1.8.2 lib

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with my Avro encoder . I've got `AvroTypeException, Expected int. Got VALUE_STRING`. Try changing the record type of Schema2 to "Person2".

Comment: can you plz share ur code snap..

Comment: have added and updated code

Comment: You get 2 when it's an int because you're parsing the Avro binary data containing the UTF8 length of the string (2 characters)... Try larger ages, I think you'll notice a pattern

Comment: Thanks,my problem  is not why am getting 2,the problem is " want to validate above json with schema2 it should say false due to "age" field is int according to schema, but in json it is string  "

Comment: @Doss, Can't share my code here, but I've just pushed part of it to github there https://github.com/hbraux/java-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/braux/tests/AvroEncoder.java and added a small Junit

Comment: Thanks for your effort,but i think you are using same schema,my question want to decode with different schema.my sample code is pushed part of it in github there https://github.com/bmdoss/java-utils/blob/master/Json2Avro.java have a take a look